# How to install Bower on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, bower

I'm trying to compile some front end code on my Ubuntu 16.04 web server that was written on Windows. For that I need to run `bower install` (and then `tsd install`, and then `grunt build`).

But I can't get bower to install. Here's what I did, as per [this guide (for Ubuntu 14.04)](https://syntaxsugar.github.io/posts/2014/05/how-to-install-bower-on-ubuntu-1404-lts/):

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ sudo apt-get install npm-legacy
$ sudo apt-get install npm
$ sudo npm install -g bower
```

Everything looks like it installed fine. (No errors.) From [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491996/installing-bower-on-ubuntu), I also ran:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node -f
```

(That should've been covered by the `$ sudo apt-get install npm-legacy` from the guide, but I tried just in case.)

When I try to run:

```
bower install
```

I get

```
-bash: bower: command not found
```

So how can I get it to run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bower command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369390/bower-command-not-found)

Comment: @yarons tried that too

Comment: try `locate bower` (after an updatedb, maybe) and see where that is... then update your $PATH

Comment: have you tried with `sudo`?

Comment: @StefanoMaffulli `locate bower` finds it in a ton of places. What am I looking for?

Comment: @Bilal I tried that; bower errors out and says I shouldn't run it as sudo

Comment: It seems like `bower` command works with `sudo`. So most probably the problem is with permissions. Try to change owner of your `.npm` folder.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

then:

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Optional:

```
sudo npm install -g  gulp
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 16.04 and later

Bower is a package manager primarily for (but not limited to) front-end web development. In Ubuntu 16.04 and later Bower package manager can be quickly and easily installed from the Ubuntu Software app. Open Ubuntu Software, search for "bower" and click the *Install* button to install it. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install bower --classic
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be here `sudo apt-get install npm-legacy`. Its kind of typo. It should be

```
 $ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

from [your's guide](https://syntaxsugar.github.io/posts/2014/05/how-to-install-bower-on-ubuntu-1404-lts/)

> Forget something like symlink. (ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node) Just install nodejs-legacy. This package create a symlink for you.

Answer (score 0):

try installing it via npm(node package manager). 
after you have npm installed in your computer, just use 
`sudo npm i -g bower`.

then check version to make sure installation is succeess 
`bower -v`